# Removing table td space in a html email

Tags: html

I am writing a html email. i have sliced an image in to three pieces and wrote simple html to show them as one image. its fien on any browser but when I send email to yahoo/hotmail/outlook it creates space after each image (bottom). see my code below.

Any idea?

```
<html><body>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="944"  width="580">

                    <tr>
                        <td height="275" >
                            <a href="http://www.example.co.uk/page/search?q=mistral&amp;searchsubmit.x=0&amp;searchsubmit.y=0" target="_blank"><img  height="275"  src="http://p4trr.emv2.com/IL/0/4/1/1101020041/1951838857.jpg" style="border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; margin: 0px;" width="580" /></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="326" >
                            <a href="http://www.example.co.uk/page/search?q=umbrian&amp;searchsubmit.x=10&amp;searchsubmit.y=10" target="_blank"><img height="326"  src="http://p4trr.emv2.com/IL/0/4/1/1101020041/183118939.jpg" style="border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; margin: 0px;" width="580" /></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="343" >
                            <a href="http://www.example.co.uk/page/search?q=balzac&amp;searchsubmit.x=0&amp;searchsubmit.y=0" target="_blank"><img  height="343"  src="http://p4trr.emv2.com/IL/0/4/1/1101020041/1581670867.jpg" style="border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; margin: 0px;" width="580" /></a></td>
                    </tr>

            </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I left you some further comments on ways you can improve this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the line height of `td` as `0` like,

**CSS**

```
<style>
 table td {
   line-height: 0;  
 }
</style>
```

Comment: Hi, just noticed this doesn't work on hotmail desktop. Any idea?

Comment: @SheikhSiddiquee Which browser you use?

Comment: I have tested in FireFox.

Answer (score 0):

> In CSS just display column in block ..

```
    td{
        display: block;
    }
```